# connect to a documnetDB cluster on my vpc from nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel, aws-documentdb

I am trying to connect to a documnetDB cluster on my vpc from my nodeJS Express project using ssh tunneling. and getting this error:

```
Mongoose connection disconnected

db.js:69
MongooseTimeoutError {message: "Server selection timed out after 15000 ms", name: "MongooseTimeoutError", reason: MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxxx-xxx…, stack: "MongooseTimeoutError: Server selection timed out a…", Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol): Object}
db.js:38
message:"Server selection timed out after 15000 ms"
name:"MongooseTimeoutError"
reason:MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND xxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx.xxxxxxx.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com xxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx.xxxxxxx.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com 
stack:"MongooseTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 15000 ms\n    at new MongooseTimeoutError
```

Before the code a few things:
I am using a package called ssh-tunnel
I disabled TLS for simplicity
I succeed to connect via MongoDB compass with exactly the same params I got here

I am woried about the fact that in the error the dstHost i am trying to connect to missing some of the address I provided in the ssh-tunnel configuration for example instead of 
xxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx.cluster-xxxxxxx.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com 
we get
xxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx.xxxxxxx.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com
Here are the code lines:

```
const config = require('./config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const fs = require('fs');
const tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');


const tunnelConfig = {
  username:'xxx-xxxx',
  // agent: process.env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK,
  host:'xxx-x-xx-xx-x.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
  privateKey: fs.readFileSync('./documentDBKeyPrivate.pem'),
  port:22,
  dstHost:'xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.xxxxx-xxxxxxxx.us-east-2.docdb.amazonaws.com',
  dstPort:27017,
  localHost:'localhost',
  localPort: 27018
};
let dbURI;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV') {
  dbURI = config.DB_CONN_STRING_DEV;

  const sshTunnel = tunnel(tunnelConfig, (error, tnl) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
  }
  // Create the database connection 
  mongoose.connect(dbURI, 
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 15000,
      poolSize: 10,
    }).catch(err => console.log(err)); 
  })
```

Comment: are you able to connect to your DocDB cluster using the mongo shell? That would be a good test to see whether the issue is in your Node.js app or the SSH tunnel setup